# Rendering image field in SSRS to fill the page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have an SSRS report that renders image field and description.

When I execute the report, the data will be rendered as two columns, description and image, but I need to view more than one image column per page, i.e. I need it to be as:

```
image1    image2   image3
image4    image5   image6
image7    image8   image9
image10   image11 image12
```

in all pages. Is it possible in SSRS?

Comment: If you know how many and what images you will render, you can create a tablix, remove the repeating group, and then include each image in each box of the tablix.

Comment: @mmarie Thanks, but as i said, i have the image as a field, that caused rendering it vertically, as a column, but i need to render the images filling all the page, please imagine the example as a page.

Comment: What do you mean? Is there more than one image per description? Or do you want multiple description-image pairs to show? In the latter case, you could have 4 columns, 2 of which were images and 2 of which were descriptions, right?

Comment: Check out my answer about [SSRS report formatting a table to display data side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721709/ssrs-report-formatting-a-table-to-display-data-side-by-side). (Closing as duplicate)