# SSRS table display results over multiple columns

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a report to display names of students in Visual Studio 2008 SSRS.

For example I would like my table to look like this:

Student | Student Name | Student | Student Name

Student | Student Name | Student | Student Name

Basically I want to list students in two columns. The student names are coming from a SQL statement that will return four students. I am able to list them all in one columns 
i.e 
Student | Student Name

Student | Student Name

Student | Student Name

Student | Student Name

However, I was wondering if there is a way to list them going horizontally instead.

I am very new to SSRS so this might be the simplest fix, I am just not sure how to do it. 
Hopefully the question makes sense, I was having trouble researching it because I am not sure how to word exactly what I am looking to do.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1) You can change your query in your data set to add a field (Display column) and use nested one-cell tables that are filtered on the field.  For detailed instructions, see [this blog](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/).

2) Use only SSRS to create 2 tables and set the row visibility formula so every other row is shown in the first column. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721709/ssrs-report-formatting-a-table-to-display-data-side-by-side) for details.

Comment: I'll use those links to look into it. Thanks so much!

Comment: The above links gave me enough information to fix my problem. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction! I was having trouble finding resources.